# Why isn't the busy message displaying for the first execution?

Tags: r, shiny

As part of a larger app, I have some calculations that will take some time, so I would  like to signal to the user that R is busy.

I found a nice little code snippet here to do that, but it doesn't activate on the first execution of the long function.

To simulate that, here is a little MRE. I left the fontawesome stuff in there in case that is relevant, but added the word "busy" to indicate when the fa icon would appear.

The first time you load it, the word "busy" does not appear, but if you change the bins, it will appear each time after that.

Is there a way to get it to show "busy" for the first one as well? Ideally, I would not use an additional package, as I see there are packages to do this as well.

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("busy"),
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        for(i in 1:10000000){#a delay while working
          log(i)
        }

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
    
    shiny_busy <- function() {
      # use &nbsp; for some alignment, if needed
      HTML("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", paste0(
        '<span data-display-if="',
        '$(&#39;html&#39;).attr(&#39;class&#39;)==&#39;shiny-busy&#39;',
        '">',
        '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin-pulse fa-fw" style="color: #337ab7;" >busy</i>',# font-size:100px !important;# size doesn't work on the first time you hit the page
        '</span>'
      ))
    }
    
    output$busy<-renderUI({
      shiny_busy()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for shiny busy to be run in a renderUI call as it is fully static and it does no depend on any reactivity. You can place it directly in the UI. See the code below.

Regarding why your version does not work, the short answer is that when you start the application the HTML code that place the busy element is not yet in the web page as the render UI has not yet run. In fact both the plot output and the render UI appear at the "same time"/same reactive cycle when the app starts. Meaning they both are added to the view at the same time. That is why it works in the second pass as the HTML showing the busy is already loaded.

A longer more general explanation can be seen in:
https://mastering-shiny.org/reactive-graph.html

```r
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(


    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
         # BUSY CODE IS HERE NOW
            HTML("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", paste0(
        '<span data-display-if="',
        '$(&#39;html&#39;).attr(&#39;class&#39;)==&#39;shiny-busy&#39;',
        '">',
        '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin-pulse fa-fw" style="color: #337ab7;" >busy</i>',# font-size:100px !important;# size doesn't work on the first time you hit the page
        '</span>'
      )),
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      message("plotting")
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        for(i in 1:10000000){#a delay while working
          log(i)
        }

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
    

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That is super helpful, as is the link to reactive graph. In the app it is actually a table, but I assume that the logic is the same. Thank you!